# Covering a space by cones

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, at.algebraic-topology, gt.geometric-topology, convex-geometry, convex-analysis

Let $X\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ be some connected and bounded $n$-dimensional manifold, e.g. a space homeomorphic to an open/closed ball with possibly some parts of it being removed.

I am interested in finding the minimum number of cones, whose vertices lie in $X$, and whose union contains $X$, or rather some bounds on this number.

One hope is that the rank of something like singular/simplicial homology can provide some, I presume, lower bounded to this. Or maybe covering by cones would allow to define another homology theory.

I am quite unfamiliar with the literature that are possibly related to this, and I would appreciate any comment or advise on this.

Comment: You should read about Lusternik-Schnirelmann category.  (It is not exactly the invariant that you ask about, but is similar.)

Comment: Doesn't this appear in the study of topological complexity as well?